# Fast replace table in T-SQL with another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have two tables with same structure (keys/columns/etc). I want to replace data in first table with data from second one. I use following code to do it:

```
DROP TABLE T1

SELECT *
INTO T1
FROM T2

DROP TABLE T2
```

but this code is slow enough when T2 is large. T2 table is temporary so I want to rewrite it as:

```
drop table T1

EXEC sp_rename 'T2', 'T1'
```

This should execute very fast for any size table, but am I missing something here? Some side effects that may break this code? I'm not very familiar with dynamic SQL so please advice.

Comment: Hmm...Renaming tables looks like XY-problem for me. What is actual problem you are trying to solve? Probably it will be better just to create a view with union of data from temporary and permanent tables or something like this?

Comment: I have a table that should be syncronized from web. When I get an updated version of table I should drop the old one and replace it with new. And I have several performance problems with current design (pass data from C# BL layer as UDTT, then `MERGE` it into result table), so I want to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renaming the tables should be fine.  Sometimes, there can be issues with triggers or foreign key constraints (and the like).  However, you are dropping `T1` anyway, so this is not a concern.

The one issue is where the data is actually stored.  If by temporary table, you mean a table name that starts with `#`, then this is not a good approach, because temporary tables are often stored separately from other tables.  Instead, create the table in the same place where `T1` would be stored, perhaps calling it something like `temp_T1`.

You might want to revisit your logic to see if there is a way to "reconstruct" T1 in place.  However, when there are large numbers of updates and deletes in the processing, recreating the table is often the fastest approach.